# MVC C# check if user is authenticated on ajax requests

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-ajax

How is the correct way to validate if a user is authenticated when doing an ajax request?

Until now I used a `JSonResult` with `AllowAnonymous`, but now I want to validate if the user is authenticated because I will need data from the authenticated user to perform some actions. I don't want to use hidden fields in the view, because this is not secure, and I want to do it using ajax because I don't want the page to refresh. Is there a way to validate authentication in ajax requests? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Please give ajax code.Because if you want to navigate login page to home is not possible by ajax call.

Comment: can't help unless you share the code.

Comment: I don't have code yet, I'm planning an application and I need to solve this issue. Imagine that you have are developing a social network. You have photos and you want to have a 'LIKE' button. You want this button to perfrom an ajax post. On the server side, I need to store the LIKE to the database, and I want to assign a user ID to that LIKE, so I need to know if the user is authenticated and get his ID. Is this possible with ajax?

Comment: Please provide us with code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I understood you correctly but in you controller method where you return JsonResult you can check either

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

or

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

if true then you can do your extra things for logged in user.

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
   if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      //Do actions for logged in user
   }
   else{

   } 
}
```

Comment: When you do an ajax request via jquery, do you have that?

Comment: if it's not a cross domain request then yes. jquery Ajax send cookie for same domain.

Comment: Great, did't know about it. Thanks!

Comment: It should be pointed out that this will only work if you're hitting an *MVC* action. If the action is a Web Api action, this will fail, because Web Api does not support cookies, or state of any kind for that matter. In that scenario, you would have to do something like pass a bearer token in an `Authorization` header for the request.